# Visual Studio 2013 stuck applying Visual Studio Core Features

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installation, windows-10

I'm currently trying to install VS2013 on Windows 10 preview, but it keeps getting stuck on this spot:

[image]

I let it sit there all last night (about 12 hours), and it didn't move at all. There aren't any errors thrown, it just sits there silently with those dots running across the bottom.

I'm using the web installer.

Comment: try the update 4. The update 2 is a bit old, maybe it has issues with Win10.

Comment: I had the same problem installing vs2015 community... Restart the pc to continue working